# How to broadcast along batch dimension with Tensorflow functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In some applications, like slot attention (implemented in Pytorch [here](https://github.com/lucidrains/slot-attention/blob/master/slot_attention/slot_attention.py)), it is necessary to broadcast along the batch dimension. However, I cannot see how to do this with the functional API. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf
const = tf.ones((1,4))
input = tf.keras.layers.Input((4))

const = tf.broadcast_to(const, input.shape)
```

throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (None, 4)
```

Thus, I resort to subclassing `tf.keras.Model`, but I would like to keep my code in the functional API. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found an answer to this by using `tf.keras.backend.shape`:

```
const = tf.ones((1,4))
input = tf.keras.layers.Input((4))

const = tf.broadcast_to(const, [tf.keras.backend.shape(input)[0], 4] )

# Shape of const is now (None, 4)
```